# Change content in About menu item

Tags: macos, cocoa

I don't know how to change the content of About in my OS X app.

I want to change it to "Engineering by,Human Interface Design,Testing"

Comment: Hey,Thanks Josh Caswell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xcode go to the folder "Supporting Files" and double-click the file **Credits.rtf**

[image]

Comment: Oh my gosh!! It was so easy thank you man..!! I really appreciate it!! :)